# Working on a responsive site, text slightly breaks with media query

Tags: text, responsive-design, media-queries

I've got a one-page responsive site I'm working on. It works for the most part the way I want it to, but there's a part where text breaks when resizing the browser width.

Here's the website:
http://vitaliyg.com

The text that breaks is the large tag line. It breaks around 780px browser width--the word "challenge" drops down to the next line for some reason. Can't figure out why.

I've replicated this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser gets around 780px wide the tagline has `font-size:50px` and the parent div .tencol has `width:82.7%` and the tagline is forced to break. At browser width 767px .tencol gets `width:auto` which allows the tagline to expand for a little while longer, but then as the browser continues to shrink the tagline breaks once more.

In your style.css, you only have the h2 font-size declared with `@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-height: 1280px)`. You'll need to add additional breakpoints for the h2 font-size to breath.

Something like:
 `@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width: 787px) {
h2 {font-size:45px;}} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 788px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
h2 {font-size:50px;}}`

Experiment with the breakpoints until you're comfortable with the result.

Comment: Thanks for shining some perspective on this. I've adjusted some font sizes very subtly and I think it transitions smoothly now. Thanks!